# Use Python oauth2 to send params to Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I created an endpoint in python (using flask) to retrieve tweets from twitter following their example [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/single-user)

Using the [oauth2](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2) package, I can send the request to twitter no problem. However, I want to send parameters via the post_body variable so I can tailor the tweets retrieved. From what I read about oauth2, this is supposed to be a byte string. And setting `post_body=b""` works. But I can't figure out how to pass params (like count=3) as a byte string. I tried setting params to `bytes('count=3','utf-8)` and `'count=3'.encode('utf-8')`. I continue to get a 500 error from twitter and `ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` from the app.

Sort of a python n00b, so some deeper understanding of why this has to be bytes and how to convert from strings to bytes would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import oauth2
import json
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, send_from_directory
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

CONSUMER_KEY = os.environ.get('CONSUMER_KEY')
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.environ.get('CONSUMER_SECRET')
TOKEN_KEY = os.environ.get('TOKEN_KEY')
TOKEN_SECRET = os.environ.get('TOKEN_SECRET')

TWITTER_API = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'

def create_app(config=None):
    flask_app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='public')
    create_routes(flask_app)
    return flask_app

def create_routes(app):
    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def handle_404(e):
        return render_template('404.html'), 404

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def no_index():
        return send_from_directory('public', 'index.html')

    @app.route('/<path:filename>', methods=['GET'])
    def serve_static(filename):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('public', filename)):
            return send_from_directory('public', '{}/index.html'.format(filename))
        elif os.path.isfile(os.path.join('public', filename)):
            return send_from_directory('public', filename)
        return render_template('404.html'), 404

    @app.route('/twitter', methods=['GET'])
    def twitter():
        params = bytes('count=3', 'utf-8')
        get_tweets = twitter_oauth_req(TWITTER_API, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET, params)
        return jsonify(get_tweets), 200

def twitter_oauth_req(url, c_key, c_secret, t_key, t_secret, post_body, http_method="GET", http_headers=None):
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=c_key, secret=c_secret)
    token = oauth2.Token(key=t_key, secret=t_secret)
    client = oauth2.Client(consumer, token)
    try:
        resp, t_response = client.request( url, method=http_method, body=post_body, headers=http_headers )
        return_json = json.loads(t_json)
    except Exception as e:
        return_json = '[]'
        print(e)
    return return_json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```